# how can authors to define custom pages?

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, author

I have a options page and i use [this](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/) code.

I want this, I add author id on sometext field (e.g 3,2,5,11 ) and my author.php redirect custom author page.

My author.php

```
<?php $post = $wp_query->post;
$options = get_option('sample_theme_options');
 if (is_author( array($options['sometext']) ) ) {
 include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/brand.php');
}
else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/customauthor.php');
}
?>
```

Im adding Some Text field number like this 3,2,5,11

```
 <?php echo  $options['sometext']; ?>
```

And code Output: 3,2,5,11

But my author.php not working good. Just first id working other id not working.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;
$options = get_option( 'sample_theme_options' );
$authors = explode( ',', $options['sometext'] );

if ( is_author( $authors ) ) {
    include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/brand.php' );
} else {
    include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/customauthor.php' );
}

?>
```

This way, you're *always* sure that `$authors` contains an array.